# How to draw 3D Cartesian coordinate frame using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I draw a coordinate frames in Matlab which looks like in the link [3D coordinate frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nefST.jpg) that different axis has different color?For example, the red line segment means x-axis, the green line segment means y-axis and the blue line segment meas z-axis.

Comment: You want  to change the axis color or to make the small marks on the plot be new axis?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I want to plot  3D small marks with colorful axis that looks like in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the `line` command.  You specify the X Y Z coordinates of the origin and then some length as the delta from the origin.

```
% origin
origin = [1 2 3];
% length of frame vectors
delta = 10;
% x-axis
line('XData', [origin(1) origin(1) + delta], 'YData', [origin(2) origin(2)],...
    'ZData', [origin(3) origin(3)], 'Color','r');
% y-axis
line('XData', [origin(1) origin(1)], 'YData', [origin(2) origin(2) + delta],...
    'ZData', [origin(3) origin(3)], 'Color','g');
% z-axis
line('XData', [origin(1) origin(1)], 'YData', [origin(2) origin(2)],...
    'ZData', [origin(3) origin(3) + delta], 'Color','b');
```